# complicated fetch from cursor

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Suppose I have a table `conf` with primary key `PK`:

```
Conf
------------------
PK  A    B     C
------------------
1   Y    Y     Y
2   Y          Y
3   Y    
------------------
```

I have another table temp:

```
Temp
------------------
PK  A    B     C
------------------
1   ab   cd    ef
1   null cd    ef
2   cd         pq
3   dn    
------------------
```

I need to fetch all the names of the column and PK from the `conf` table which have value `Y`, for example:

```
1  A  B  C
2  A  C
3  A
```

These values need to be compared with `temp` table rows, and check whether the value of the column fetched are null inside that column, and if so throw an error.

For example, for `2 A C` we need to compare with A and C columns of temp table having `2` as `PK`.

My question is how can I fetch the below record in cursor:

```
1  A  B  C
2  A  C
3  A
```

I am not getting an optimized solution for that. It can be done by comparing all columns of the `conf` table with the `temp` table, but there can be more than 15 columns.

The outline of the algorithm is:

```
fetch all column name from conf table having value 'Y'
loop
    fetch all the columns from temp table with primary key from outer cursor
    loop
        On the basis of column name from outer cursor check the value of column
        of temp table for its nullability 
    end loop;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is still better to use a query like:

```
select c.*, t.*
  from conf c, temp t
 where c.pk = t.pk
   and ((c.a = 'Y' and t.a is null) or (c.b = 'Y' and t.b is null) or
       (c.c = 'Y' and t.c is null))
```

if you don't know the columns, you can create the query dynamically by looping on user_tab_cols / all_tab_cols:

```
declare

  sql_str varchar2(32767);

  cursor c_col is
    select tc.column_name
      from user_tab_cols tc
     where tc.table_name = 'CONF' and tc.column_name <> 'PK';

  type rc_bad_rows is ref cursor;
  c_bad_rows rc_bad_rows;

  val number;

  is_first boolean := true;

begin

  sql_str := 'select t.pk from conf c, temp t ' ||
             'where c.pk = t.pk and (';

  for r in c_col loop

    if not is_first then
      sql_str := sql_str || ' or ';
    end if;

    is_first := false;

    sql_str := sql_str || '(c.' || r.column_name || ' = ''Y'' and t.' ||
               r.column_name || ' is null)';

  end loop;

  sql_str := sql_str || ')';

  dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);

  open c_bad_rows for sql_str;

  loop
    fetch c_bad_rows
      into val;
    exit when c_bad_rows%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(val);
  end loop;

  close c_bad_rows;
end;
```

This code may not be the best, but it is an example ...